# Saved SSIS package not working and not executing anything

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

[image]

I am trying to create an SSIS package that will

1. Delete the contents of a table and
2. Load a flat file to that that table.

When I created it and ran it the first time, it ran fine and did exactly what I wanted. I saved it the other day and opened it today to run the package and it does nothing. I verified by removing the load portion and only running the SQL command portion, the table was not affected.

The Data Flow task is the portion where it reads the .csv and loads to the table.  I am not sure why it would have worked when I created it and then suddenly stopped doing anything. I have attached the output message I am getting below. It doesn't even go to the second stage of the package where I can see the process in action (green check marks etc.). Any thoughts?

For reference I am using Visual Studio 2017 w/ SSDT

Here is the output:

```
------ Build started: Project: Load_Top_Up_Table_v2 (SQL Server 2017), Configuration: Development ------
Build started: SQL Server Integration Services project: Incremental ...
Build complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Ugh - this answer doesn't seem to fix the issue and neither does the Answer for the answer in the Closed section.

Answer (score 1):

Go to project configurarion >> debugging. Check that `StartAction` is set to `Execute Package`, and `Start Object` is set to the `<Active Package>`:

[image]

**Then, if clicking on the start button still not working, in the Visual studio menu strip, Go to Debug >> Start**